# Get Async task result in a callback in an Fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am starting fresh with android and not able to figure out how to get an http  json response back in a Fragment. In my activity I am easily able to do so using callback function but it seems difficult to accomplish the same in Fragment.

Any help would really appreciated.

```
//SaleFragment.java
public class SaleFragment extends Fragment{

public static final String ARG_CLIENT_NUMBER = "client_number";
private ListView salesListView;
private View rootView;

public SaleFragment() {
// Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}

@Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sale, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_CLIENT_NUMBER);
            try{
                     SaleStackJSON sale_json = new SaleStackJSON();
                     sale_json.execute("http://test.url/getJson"); //url to retrieve json
                     // do processing on the result (I do not know how to retrieve them here after the request)

           }catch(Exception e){
                      //  resultView.setText(e.getMessage());
              }

        return rootView;
   }
```

My JSON class is as follows:

```
// SaleStackJSON.java
public class SaleStackJSON   extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONArray jArray = null;
    String error_text="";
    JSONObject j = null;
    TextView resultView;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            setResult(sb.toString());

            //     this.jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }


        return getResult();
    }


    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
    public void setResult(String result) {
        this.result = result;
    }
}
```

Edit 1: I use the following code for populating my frontend. (Display results)

```
        JSONArray jArray;
        ArrayList all_sales = new ArrayList();
        try {
            jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            int total_retail_outlets = jArray.length();
            //LinearLayout scrollable_sale_layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrollable_sale_layout);
            for (int i = 0; i < total_retail_outlets; i++) {
                    JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String customer_name = jObj.getString("name");
                    String created_at = jObj.getString("created_at");
                    String quantity = jObj.getString("quantity");
                    String billing_amount = jObj.getString("billing_amount");
                    String discount_percentage = jObj.getString("discount_percentage");
                    String discount = jObj.getString("discount");
                    String total = jObj.getString("total");
                    SalesItem salesData = new SalesItem();
                    salesData.setBilling_amount(billing_amount);
                    salesData.setCreated_at(created_at);
                    salesData.setCustomer_name(customer_name);
                    salesData.setDiscount(discount);
                    salesData.setDiscount_percentage(discount_percentage);
                    salesData.setQuantity(quantity);
                    salesData.setTotal(total);

                    all_sales.add(salesData);
                }

            salesListView.setAdapter(new CustomSaleListAdapter(getActivity(), all_sales));


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: what do you want to do after getting result?

Comment: I have updated the code of what I would like to do. Thanks.

Comment: You could have the async task class as the inner class of the fragment, which would definitely make things a lot easier, unless you want to use the async task from a lot of other fragments. If you had an inner class, you could directly access the fragment UI objects from the async task. If you would however like to use a separate class for the async task, then maybe a local broascast or a handler can help communicate between the two classes.

Comment: I am using the same Async task in some more activities. So, one of the solution would be to just create a inner class. Thats a good idea. But, I will just wait for a more concrete solution. Can you just share some code for the second part of your comment..

Comment: http://masl.cis.gvsu.edu/2010/04/05/android-code-sample-asynchronous-http-connections/  uses handlers and a nice, async framework for http calls. Handlers can be defined and will be calledBack anywhere in code other than in a runnable.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Will definitely go through the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry about any typo; my solution is:

first it is good idea to process your response in doInBackground method because it makes UI thread be less busy so:

```
 public class SaleStackJSON   extends AsyncTask<String, Void,  ArrayList<SalesItem>>
```

and in doInBackground do something like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    // Download JSON data from URL
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();


        //     this.jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    ArrayList<SalesItem> all_sales = new ArrayList<SalesItem>();
    JSONArray jArray;
    try {
        jArray = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
        int total_retail_outlets = jArray.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < total_retail_outlets; i++) {
                JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String customer_name = jObj.getString("name");
                String created_at = jObj.getString("created_at");
                String quantity = jObj.getString("quantity");
                String billing_amount = jObj.getString("billing_amount");
                String discount_percentage = jObj.getString("discount_percentage");
                String discount = jObj.getString("discount");
                String total = jObj.getString("total");
                SalesItem salesData = new SalesItem();
                salesData.setBilling_amount(billing_amount);
                salesData.setCreated_at(created_at);
                salesData.setCustomer_name(customer_name);
                salesData.setDiscount(discount);
                salesData.setDiscount_percentage(discount_percentage);
                salesData.setQuantity(quantity);
                salesData.setTotal(total);

                all_sales.add(salesData);
            }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    return all_sales;
}
```

now let's go to final change:

```
 protected void onPostExecute( ArrayList<SalesItem> result) {

 salesListView.setAdapter(new CustomSaleListAdapter(getActivity(), result[0]));

}
```

Comment: Great, so got it working by this idea. I made a mistake of doing everything in the Fragment instead I should have done it here in JSON class. However, your code has some mistake. Please rectify it so that I can mark it right. Firstly, doInBackground can just return String and not the list. Secondly in onPostExecute getActivity is not possible. We have to initialize the context in the constructor. Thanks a lot though. Please change it so I can mark it right..!

Comment: `doInBackground can just return String and not the list` i changed my header so i think you did not notice that.`AsyncTask<String, Void,  ArrayList<SalesItem>>` and except using `getActivity()` use `SaleFragment.this.getActivity();`

Comment: i have not edited it to know your result. i think that solution must work except last line getActivity().

Answer (score 0):

```
This will might help u I do also got the same problem but resolved at the end


    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (null != pd && pd.isShowing()) {
                pd.dismiss();
            }
            String message="";
            try
            {
                message=result.getString("message");
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                if(result!=null&&message.equalsIgnoreCase("Invalid User"))
                {
                    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity,LoginRegisterOptionScreen.class));
                    activity.finish();
                }
                else
                {
                    if(fragment!=null)
                    {
                        if(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("ProfileFragment"))
                        {
                            ((ProfileFragment) fragment).getServerResponse(result); 
                        }
                        else if (fragment.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("reviewScreen")) {
                            ((ReviewScreen) fragment).getServerResponse(result);
                        }
                        else if (fragment.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("ReviewEditable")) {
                            ((ReviewEditable) fragment).getServerResponse(result);
                        }
                        //          else if(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("FavoritesFragment"))
                        //          {
                        //              ((FavoritesFragment) fragment).getServerResponse(result); 
                        //          }

                    }
                    else if (activity != null) {
                        if (activity.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("RegisterScreen2")) {
                            ((RegisterScreen2) activity).getServerResponse(result);
                        }
                        else if (activity.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("LoginScreen")) {
                            ((LoginScreen) activity).getServerResponse(result);
                        }

                        else if (activity.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("changePassword")) {
                            ((changePassword) activity).getServerResponse(result);
                        }


                        //          else if (activity.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("googlemap")) {
                        //              ((googlemap) activity).getServerResponse(result);
                        //          }
                        //          else if (activity.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("chatter")) {
                        //              try {
                        //                  ((chatter) activity).getServerResponse(result);
                        //              } catch (JSONException e) {
                        //                  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        //                  e.printStackTrace();
                        //              }
                        //          }
                        //          else if (activity.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("Chatlist")) {
                        //              ((Chatlist) activity).getServerResponse(result);
                        //          }


                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```